# creating indexes with new MongoDB C++ driver

Tags: mongodb, c++11

I have been trying to get the new C++ driver for mongodb working. At this point I can create new data bases/collections, add documents, and generate queries. My problem is when I try to create an index using the create_index method.

The syntax from the documentation is:

bsoncxx::document::value mongocxx::collection::create_index     (   bsoncxx::document::view_or_value    keys,
        const options::index &      options = options::index()

I get the keys part, it looks like {'some type': 1}

What I am having problems with is trying to figure out what the options part should look like. I am relatively new to c++11 (but have lots of C and old C++ experience) and am having problems trying to parse the options part. Can someone provide an example of what the options part should look like assuming I am trying to specify a "name" and something else like "default_language"??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please see the [mongocxx index example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/examples/mongocxx/index.cpp), which should provide some good examples of how this works.

In general, you will construct an object of type `mongocxx::options::index` on the stack, call methods on that object to set options as you see fit (for your cases, see the [`mongocxx::options::index::name`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/src/mongocxx/options/index.hpp#L125) and [`mongocxx::options::index::default_language`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/stable/src/mongocxx/options/index.hpp#L244) methods), as follows:

```
db["foo"].drop();
bsoncxx::builder::stream::document index_builder;
mongocxx::options::index index_options{};
index_builder << ...
index_options.name("my_nifty_index");
index_options.default_language("spanish");
db["foo"].create_index(index_builder.view(), index_options);
```